# <c:forEach> and <h:commandLink> not able to send param to function

Tags: java, jsp, jsp-tags

I can't get the `h:command` to send `param` to the function
the cat1 has values AR array but I can't get it to send the `param` in the correct param

**JSP code**

```
<c:forEach items="${categoryBean.getSubCategoryByID(0)}" var="cat" varStatus="stat">        
<c:set var="cat1" scope="request" value="${cat}"/>
   <li>
     <c:out value="${cat1.id}" />  <c:out value="${cat1.name}" />
     <h:commandLink id="goprime" action="#{categoryBean.gotoPrimecat}" value="#{cat1.name}"> 
     <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{categoryBean.CatID}" value="#{cat1.id}" />
      </h:commandLink>
    </li>
  </c:forEach>
```

the bean code

```
public String getCatID() {
    return CatID;
}
public void setCatID(String CatID) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
   logger.info("in setter: "+CatID);
    this.CatID = CatID;
        //products = product.searchProductsByCategory(null, null, CatID); 


}

public void GotoPrimecat() throws IOException  {
    logger.info("in primercat , id: "+this.CatID);
    ExternalContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
    context.redirect("category.jsp");
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem is the name of your method. In your page the method is referenced as `categoryBean.gotoPrimecat`, while in your bean the method is `GotoPrimecat()`. Make sure the method name is exactly the same, including the case, and it should be ok. In this case your bean method should begin with a lowercase letter, which is the generally accepted style anyway.

Comment: thanks for the answer but still not working correctly, the f:setPropertyActionListener sets null value for  CatID

Comment: Does the CatID property in your bean have correctly named getters and setters?

Comment: the seeter and getter as below it seem that the cat1 is not passet to the JAVABEAN
    public String getCatID() {
        return CatID;
    }
 public void setCatID(String CatID) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
       logger.info("in setter: "+CatID);
        this.CatID = CatID;
            //products = product.searchProductsByCategory(null, null, CatID); 
        
        
    }

Comment: the setter gets null attribute "  in setter: null"

Comment: Try setting the value of the setPropertyActionListener to some hardcoded value, eg "123", and see if you still get a null value in the setter.

Comment: Hi when i try hardcoded value it works ok the problem is when i try to use the value of the <c:forEach or the <c:set

Comment: ok great, that narrows it down a bit. My suspicion is that this variable is out of scope at the time you want to use it. Is your bean request scoped? What if you try view scope?

Comment: hi it's been a Session Scoped but also tried request and view scope but both aren't working

Comment: ok, next attempt. I think I remember hearing that JSP tags and JSF tags don't play well together, although I've never tried to mix them myself. Try changing the c:foreach to ui:repeat. Remember to include the ui taglib!